# What does this bash line do? (HPC)

Tags: bash

The context here is a Beowulf HPC cluster. I will simplify the code:

```
for img in $images; do
    script=$(mktemp)
    cat > $script <<EOF ######## What does this line do?
    module load mymodule
    my_processing -with $img
    EOF

    # cat $script
    # qsub $script
done
```

The script can be printed to screen to verify all paths have been resolved correctly by uncommenting the `cat $script` line, and similarly submitted as a job by uncommenting the `qsub $script` line. I have basic understanding of the > operator, but to my understanding it is `cat`ing nothing into the `$script`... Obviously that's not what's really happening because this all works.

Comment: it's a heredoc (`<<EOF`) redirected out to a file (`> $script`)

Comment: Manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: Open `man bash` and search on `<<` and you find a detailed explanation of here-documents.

Comment: So the file descriptor in this case is `cat > $script`?

Comment: It writes the 2 lines between `cat` and `EOF` into the file `$script`.

Comment: I know what it does, just confused on the how...

Comment: `>` is redirection.  It sends the output to `$script`.  `<<` starts a here-document.

Comment: Got it. I didn't realize I could run `cat > $file`, I just thought you always had to have something before the `>`. Thanks.

Comment: When used without an argument, `cat` copies stdin to stdout.  The here-document counts as stdin.

Comment: `cat` is the simplest case of a class of programs called *filter programs*.  They process filenames specified as parameters or, if none are specified, read from standard input. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(software)#Unix