# What does "cat > somefilename <<EOF" (particularly, the greater-than and double less-than symbols) do in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

Just came across the following command:

```
cat > myspider.py <<EOF
```

But I'm not sure of the use of `>` and `<<`.

Comment: Arguably this should be two completely different questions. (Also, they're almost certainly both duplicates).

Comment: ...the `<<EOF` part is duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash

Comment: Hmm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581182/what-does-this-bash-line-do-hpc is a perfect duplicate, but has no answers (and a downvote). Closing that as a dupe of this one.

Comment: BTW, the original title was less clear because `>` and `<<` can mean different things if they were, for instance, used in a math context.

Comment: For the manual page (succinct, to the point of being terse), see [I/O Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My original title with "greater than" and "double less than" literals were intended to make the question more searchable. Or I'm wrong and the actual symbols will work just fine.

Comment: See also the SO documentation page for [bash redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/399/redirection#t=201609192341380811663)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<<EOF` is the start of a heredoc. Content after this line and prior to the next line containing only `EOF` is fed on stdin to the process `cat`.

`> myspider.py` is a stdout redirection. `myspider.py` will be truncated if it already exists (and is a regular file), and output of `cat` will be written into it.

Since `cat` with no command-line arguments (which is the case here because the redirections are interpreted as directives to the shell on how to set up the process, not passed to `cat` as arguments) reads from its input and writes to its output, the `<<EOF` indicates that following lines should be written into the process as input, and the `>myspider.py` indicates that output should be written to `myspider.py`, this thus writes everything up to the next `EOF` into `myspider.py`.

---

See:

- [The bash-hackers redirection tutorial](https://bash-hackers.gabe565.com/howto/redirection_tutorial/)
- [The Wooledge wiki entry on Heredocs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument)

Comment: the first link is now dead

Comment: @deadParrot, thank you for the notice; updated to point to a mirror.